# Why is leave-one-out cross-validation of GLM model (package=boot) failing when data contains NaN's?

Tags: r, glm

This is a fairly simple procedure - refitting GLM model with subset of data (training set) and calculating the accuracy of the prediction on the remaining data. I am trying to run a "leave-one-out" strategy on a data set (i.e. training subset is length = n-1) using the `cv.glm` function of the package `boot`.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this really the case that the function doesn't seem to handle NA's? I'm guessing that this is fairly easy to program on my own, but I would appreciate any advise if there is some other mistake that I am making. Cheers.

#### Example:

```
require(boot)

#create data
n <- 100
x <- runif(n)
e <- rnorm(n, sd=100)
a <- 5
b <- 3
y <- exp(a + b*x) + e
plot(y ~ x)
plot(y ~ x, log="y")
```

[image]

```
#make some y's NaN
set.seed(1)
y[sample(n, 0.1*n)] <- NaN

#fit glm model
df <- data.frame(y=y, x=x)
glm.fit <- glm(y ~ x, data=df, family=gaussian(link="log"))
summary(glm.fit)

#calculate mean error of prediction (leave-one-out cross-validation)
cv.res <- cv.glm(df, glm.fit)
cv.res$delta
[1] NA NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right.  The function is not set up to handle NAs.  The various options for the `na.action` argument of the `glm()` function don't really help, either.  The easiest way to deal with it, is to remove the NAs from the data frame at the outset.

```
sub <- df[!is.na(df$y), ]
glm.fit <- glm(y ~ x, data=sub, family=gaussian(link="log"))
summary(glm.fit)

# calculate mean error of prediction (leave-one-out cross-validation)
cv.res <- cv.glm(sub, glm.fit)
cv.res$delta
```